# How to spy on an inner function from same file with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following functions file:

```
// functions.js

function bar() {
  return 'bar';
}

function foo() {
  return bar();
}

export functions = {
  bar,
  foo,
};
```

And I want to test the `foo` function as following:

```
// functions.test.js

import {functions} from './functions.js';

describe('test foo', () => {
  it('should call bar', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(functions, 'bar');

    functions.foo();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

And I get the following error:

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            ^
```

Any idea what is wrong with this test?

Comment: If you're using ESM exports, try exports the function directly rather than in an object?

Comment: Don't. `expect(functions.foo()).toBe('bar')`. Test _behaviour_, not implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

You are spying on the wrong function.
`functions.bar` is not the same `bar` that is called inside the `foo` function.
`foo` is referencing `bar` that is a *standalone* function, however you are spying on a function that is *attached* to the `functions` object.

If you change your code like this it will work.

```js
export functions = {
  bar(){},
  foo(){this.bar()},
};
```

Comment: you are changing the whole structure of the exported function. bad solution.

Comment: Well, your code is not structured properly to do what you want it to do. Read about [Understanding Context in Javascript Object Literals](https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/context-object-literals/)